# How can i center this second nav bar in marerializecss?

Tags: html, css

i have a navigation bar i made using MaterializeCSS and i was wondering how to center the bottom one.
Here is my code:

```
    <nav class="nav-extended">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">TEMP LOGO TEXT</a>
      <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-content container">
      <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
        <center>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">Partnerships</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">Work Schemes</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">Lesson Plans</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">Guidance</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#">Apply</a></li>
        </center>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is an image of what it currently looks like. (I tried using  tags it didnt work)
[image: Current result]

Comment: without additional CSS, it is already centered, check my answer. Do you have any addition css could affect those tabs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<center>` tag is not supported anymore for HTML5, you should take it out.

Using latest from `materialize` and using the following allowed me to center those tabs

```
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

> ### A Complete Guide to Flexbox
>
> REF: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<nav class="nav-extended">
  <div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo center">TEMP LOGO TEXT</a>
    <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-content container">
    <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">Partnerships</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">Work Schemes</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">Lesson Plans</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">Guidance</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="#">Apply</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This seemed to work, im unsure why my references are different mhm i got the latest download from their website :/

Comment: @Joosh hm, I updated with the latest from their site, because when I saw the img you posted, there is no pink so I thought It might be the lib reference.

Comment: @Joosh they changed the css, seems like they removed display: flex from their css, but you can simple add it to your own CSS and get it centered, check my updated answer, hope it helps =D

Comment: flexbox is <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

Add this class:
`center-align` at DIV before of UL

Comment: this hasn't changed anything.